# How do I use OCIEnvNlsCreate() to always get CHAR and NCHAR data back in UTF8 encoding?

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface, nls-lang

Currently I'm using `OCIEnvCreate()` to create an OCI session handle to communicate with Oracle databases. I'd like to explicitly use UTF8 rather than relying on whatever client locale has been set, and I gather that I need to use `OCIEnvNlsCreate()` to do this. But there's something I don't understand. Here's the signature for `OCIEnvNlsCreate()`:

```
sword OCIEnvNlsCreate   ( OCIEnv        **envhpp,
                          ub4           mode,
                          dvoid         *ctxp,
                          dvoid         *(*malocfp)
                                             (dvoid *ctxp,
                                              size_t size),
                          dvoid         *(*ralocfp)
                                             (dvoid *ctxp,
                                              dvoid *memptr,
                                              size_t newsize),
                          void          (*mfreefp)
                                             (dvoid *ctxp,
                                              dvoid *memptr))
                          size_t        xtramemsz,
                          dvoid         **usrmempp
                          ub2           charset,
                          ub2           ncharset );
```

Notice `charset` and `ncharset` are integral types, not strings. So I'm guessing that I need to specify an NLS ID? So where are these NLS IDs? They're not in the OCI headers anywhere - I've grep'ed them pretty thoroughly. I know what some of the strings that should show up in `NLS_LANG` are - stuff like `"CL8MACCYRILLIC"` and `"TR8PC857"` - but their IDs don't seem to be published anywhere?

I've trawled through IDs 1-999 with `OCINlsCharSetIdToName()` which tells me that UTF8 is 871, but I have a queasy feeling about hard-coding that given that Oracle decided to not document this or make it public? And if I always use `OCINlsCharSetNameToId( handle, "UTF8" )`, I have to create a dummy session handle first (with `OCIEnvCreate()` or `OCIEnvNlsCreate()`), call `OCINlsCharSetNameToId()`, close the dummy session handle, and then call `OCIEnvNlsCreate()` again with the NLS ID?

Is this really the way this is supposed to work??? I must have this wrong...?

Comment: I like your question and I do believe it deserves a bounty  :)

Comment: What about setting NLS_LANG env, variable to AL32UTF8 before calling OCIEnvCreate?

Comment: I believe @TedMiddleton wants to avoid relying on any locale setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either try to call setenv() in C++ code before calling OCIEnvCreate().

Or check Metalink  NOTE.93358.1 SCRIPT: Where to Find Specifications of Character Encoding:

Create the "dectohex" function first by referencing the above Note:67533.1 prior to running the query below.

```
set pages 1000
col nls_charset_id for 9999
col hex for a10
col value for a20
select nls_charset_id(value) nls_charset_id,
base_convert.dec_to_hex(nls_charset_id(value)) hex, value
from v$nls_valid_values
where parameter = 'CHARACTERSET'
order by nls_charset_id(value);

NLS_CHARSET_ID HEX        VALUE
-------------- ---------- --------------------
1              1          US7ASCII
...


//Note: the characterset constant number for UTF8 = 871 can be retrieved in NOTE.93358.1 SCRIPT: Where to Find Specifications of Character Encoding
ub2 cs = 871, ncs =871;
sword res = OCICALL(OCIEnvNlsCreate(&_handle, oci_mode, 0/*ctxp*/, 0, 0, 0, 0/*xtramem_sz*/, 0/*usrmempp*/, cs, ncs));
```

IMHO it is safe to be hardcoded. The same value is also hardcoded on DB side.
PS: Conversion into target charset is performed on DB client side. Oracle Instant client libs support only US7ASCII and AL32UTF8 charsets.

Comment: I agree the 871 would be safe to hard-code for `UTF8`.  For more bizarre (well, less common) locales this answer is great.

Comment: @ibre5041, great answer. I will grant you the bounty mate